# why fill() affects all functions in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Whenever I use `fill()` in p5.js, all of my user-defined functions get affected by it. WHY?

Here is my code:

```
let a1 = a2 = 0;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  fill(100,100,10);
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  rotate(a1);
  ellipse(20,20,50,50);
  a1+=1;
  (20,20);
}

function rotateAbout(x,y){
  translate(x,y);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  rotate(a2);
  ellipse(15,15,20,20);
  a2+=1;
}
```

Comment: what is `(20,20);` ?

Comment: Why **wouldn't** they be affected by it?

Answer (score 5):

The function [`fill()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/fill) doesn't fill anything. It sets the color used to fill shapes. This color is a global state.
In processing a shape is filled by the current fill color. This causes that all the objects which are draw after calling `fill` get filled by the color which was set.
You've to call [`noFill()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noFill) to disable filling the geometry.

e.g

The objects which are drawn in `rotateAbout` will be filled if you do:

```java
fill(100, 100, 10);
rotateAbout(0, 0);
```

They will be not filled if you do:

```java
noFill();
rotateAbout(0, 0);
```

Note, states like the fill color are even kept beyond frames. If you set the fill color at the end of `draw`, the color will be still set, when `draw` is entered the next time.
The state is kept till the next call to `fill()` or `noFill()`.